# create name-spaced scaffold without prefixing model with name space in rails4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to maintain comments tables under each type of users.
like if user is admin 
i want to have it under admin namespace.
if user is moderator then moderator namespace will have comment resource under it.

When i generate scaffold for them rails prefixes table name with namespace.

```
$ rails g scaffold "admin::comment" name:string{22} --skip-namespace
```

i want to avoid this prefixing and just want to organise code under folders. even skip table generation.

Comment: So you want to generate a scaffold under `admin` without a migration and the model to not be namespaced? Then why the hell do you want to use the scaffold generator?

Comment: @Vapire bcoz scaffold generator creates views and controllers and saves time.

Comment: True, but if you don't want the migration and the model then use the `scaffold_controller` generator.